# Importing multiple xml files, filter, then output to different xml format in SSIS

Tags: sql, xml, ssis

I have a task that requires me to pull in a set of xml files, which are all related, then pick out a subset of records from these files, transform some columns, and export to a a single xml file using a different format.

I'm new to SSIS, and so far I've managed to first import two of the xml files (for simplicity, starting with just two files).

The first file we can call "Item", containing some basic metadata, amongst those an ID, which is used to identify related records in the second file "Milestones". I filter my "valid records" using a lookup transformation in my dataflow - now I have the valid Item ID's to fetch the records I need. I funnel these valid ID's (along with the rest of the columns from Item.xml through a Sort, then into a merge join.

The second file is structured with 2 outputs, one containing two columns (ItemID and RowID). The second containing all of the Milestone related data plus a RowID. I put these through a inner merge join, based on RowID, so I have the ItemID in with the milestone data. Then I do a full outer join merge join on both files, using ItemID.

This gives me data sort of like this:

- ItemID[1] - MilestoneData[2]
- ItemID[1] - MilestoneData[3]
- ItemID[1] - MilestoneData[4]
- ItemID[1] - MilestoneData[5]
- ItemID[2] - MilestoneData[6]
- ItemID[2] - MilestoneData[7]
- ItemID[2] - MilestoneData[8]

I can put this data through derived column transformations to create the columns of data I actually need, but I can't see how to structure this in a relational way/normalize it into a different xml format.

The idea is to output something like:

```
<item id="1">
      <Milestone id="2">
      <Milestone />
      <Milestone id="3">
      <Milestone />
</item>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE:**
A bit more detailed picture of what I have, and what I'd like to achieve:

Item.xml:

```
 <Items>
     <Item ItemID="1">
         <Title>
         Data
         </Title>
     </Item>
     <Item ItemID="2">
          ...
     </Item>
     ...
 </Items>
```

Milestone.xml:

```
  <Milestones>
  <Item ItemID="2">
       <MS id="3">
            <MS_DATA>
             Data
            </MS_DATA>
       </MS>
       <MS id="4">
            <MS_DATA>
             Data
            </MS_DATA>
       </MS>
   </Item>
   <Item ItemID="3">
       <MS id="5">
            <MS_DATA>
             Data
            </MS_DATA>
       </MS>
   </item>
 </Milestones>
```

The way it's presented in SSIS when I use XML source, is not entirely intuitive, meaning the Item rows and the MS rows are two seperate outputs. I had to run these through a join in order to get the Milestones that corresponds to specific Items. No problem here, then run it through a full outer join with the items, so I get a flattened table with multiple rows containing obviously the same data for an Item and with different data for the MS. Basically I get what I tried to show in my table, lots of redundant Item data, for each unique MilestoneData.

In the end it has to look similar to:

```
 <NewItems>
 <myNewItem ItemID="2">
       <SomeDataDirectlyFromItem>
            e.g. Title
       </SomeDataDirectlyFromItem>
       <DataConstructedFromMultipleColumnsInItem>
            <MyMilestones>
                  <MS_DATA_TRANSFORMED MSID="3">
                       data
                  </MS_DATA_TRANSFORMED>
                  <MS_DATA_TRANSFORMED MSID="4">
                       data
                  </MS_DATA_TRANSFORMED>
            </MyMilestones>
       </DataConstructedFromMultipleColumnsInItem>
  <myNewItem ItemID="3">
       <SomeDataDirectlyFromItem>
            e.g. Title
       </SomeDataDirectlyFromItem>
       <DataConstructedFromMultipleColumnsInItem>
            <MyMilestones>
                  <MS_DATA_TRANSFORMED MSID="5">
                       data
                  </MS_DATA_TRANSFORMED>
            </MyMilestones>
       </DataConstructedFromMultipleColumnsInItem>
 </myNewItem>
 <myNewItem ItemID="4">
       <SomeDataDirectlyFromItem>
            e.g. Title
       </SomeDataDirectlyFromItem>
       <DataConstructedFromMultipleColumnsInItem>
            <MyMilestones></MyMilestones>
       </DataConstructedFromMultipleColumnsInItem>
 </myNewItem>
 </NewItems>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to handle this using a `script component` with the component type `transformation`. As you are new to ssis, i assume you haven't used this before. So basically you

- define input columns, your component will expect (i.e. column `input_xml` containing `ItemID[1] - MilestoneData[2];...`
- use c# to create a logic which cuts and sticks together
- define output columns your component will use to deliver the transformed row

You will face the problem that one row will probably be used two times in the end, like i.e.

`ItemID[1] - MilestoneData[2]`

will result in

```
<item id="1">
      <Milestone id="2">
```

I have done something pretty similar using [Pentaho kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/), even without using something like a `script component` in which you define own logic. But i guess ssis has a lack of tasks here.

Answer (score 0):

How about importing the XML into relational tables ( eg in tempdb ) then using FOR XML PATH to reconstruct the XML?  FOR XML PATH offers a high degree of control over how you want the XML to look.  A very simple example below:

```
CREATE TABLE #items ( itemId INT PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(50) NULL )
CREATE TABLE #milestones ( itemId INT, msId INT, msData VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ( itemId, msId ) )
GO

DECLARE @itemsXML XML

SELECT @itemsXML = x.y
FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'c:\temp\items.xml', SINGLE_CLOB ) x(y)

INSERT INTO #items ( itemId, title )
SELECT 
    i.c.value('@ItemID', 'INT' ),
    i.c.value('(Title/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)' )
FROM @itemsXML.nodes('Items/Item') i(c)
GO


DECLARE @milestoneXML XML

SELECT @milestoneXML = x.y
FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'c:\temp\milestone.xml', SINGLE_CLOB ) x(y)

INSERT INTO #milestones ( itemId, msId, msData )
SELECT 
    i.c.value('@ItemID', 'INT' ),
    i.c.value('(MS/@id)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)' ) msId,
    i.c.value('(MS/MS_DATA/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)' ) msData
FROM @milestoneXML.nodes('Milestones/Item') i(c)
GO

SELECT 
    i.itemId AS "@ItemID"
FROM #items i
    INNER JOIN #milestones ms ON i.itemId = ms.itemId
FOR XML PATH('myNewItem'), ROOT('NewItems'), TYPE


DROP TABLE #items 
DROP TABLE #milestones
```

Comment: Consider writing a comment if want to ask something about the OP's question.